# keying in password through a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, terminal

I have written a bash script that downloads several movies from different directories in a remote cluster. My problem is that the bash file asks me my password in the remote cluster for downloading "each" of the movies.

I am wondering if there is a way to keying in the password only once and download all the movies. I really appreciate it if someone can help. My bash script is:

```
##! /bin/bash
direc1='foldername1 foldernameg foldername7 foldernames'
for AR     in $direc1       ;do
movname="$AR".avi
for ART     in $movname       ;do
DatFile1="$AR"
DatFile2="$ART"
echo "#######################--NEW--####--DOWNLOAD--###############################"
scp -p -r cluster/directory/$DatFile1/$DatFile2 /home/folder3       

done
done
```

The output is like this:

```
#######################--NEW--####--DOWNLOAD--###############################
your password: 
foldername1.avi                                                                                                        100% 7580KB   1.5MB/s   00:04    
#######################--NEW--####--DOWNLOAD--###############################
your password: 
foldernameg.avi                                                                                                        100% 7580KB   1.1MB/s   00:02   
#######################--NEW--####--DOWNLOAD--###############################
your password: 
foldername7.avi                                                                                                        100% 7580KB   1.7MB/s   00:05    
#######################--NEW--####--DOWNLOAD--###############################
your password: 
foldernames.avi                                                                                                        100% 7580KB   1.9MB/s   00:07
```

In the above output when the message " your password:" appears, I need to key in my password to be able to download each movie.

Comment: Yes, you can use key-based authentication.  I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1):

`scp` uses `ssh`.  Therefore, as long as you have ssh public-key login enabled in the `sshd` config, your `ssh` public key has no password, and your public key was added to the authorized keys, then you can use `scp` without a password.

1. Generate an ssh key on your client (i.e. where you are running your scp script). Leave the password empty for passwordless login.

```
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/stew/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/stew/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/stew/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:CB8ztwpXrT7lWQj/3W+8IAoHwqTelEBva9/aA7u2w3w stew@stewbian
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|   .             |
|  . .    .       |
|   ..++ + .      |
|    *ooB = .     |
|   ..B+.S + .    |
|  . +oo+oo + . . |
|   . .+o=oo......|
|       *=E. . . +|
|      .+=o.    oo|
+----[SHA256]-----+
$
```

2. Ensure the ssh server (remote machine) accepts public keys

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep PubkeyAuthentication
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

If it shows `PubkeyAuthentication no`, then change the file and `systemctl restart sshd`.

3. Add your public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the remote server.  This can be done with `ssh-copy-id <user>@<server>` or by manually appending the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` which we made in step 1 from your local machine to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the server.

Answer (score 0):

key-based authentication is the best way to go. If the remote side is not configured for this, this kind of problem is what [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) is for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set timeout -1

# enter your password once
stty -echo
send_user -- "Enter your password for the cluster: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set pass $expect_out(1,string)

set folders {
    foldername1
    foldernameg
    foldername7
    foldernames
}

foreach f $folders
    spawn scp -p -r cluster/directory/$f/$f.avi /home/folder3
    expect {
        "your password:" { send "$pass\r"; exp_continue }
        eof
    }
}
```